# Having trouble with defining labels in python 3

Tags: python

I'm writing a test program that is in a way like an inventory tracker for a hire store. I'm working on checking the user's entered data, but I'm constantly getting a NameError with one of my function not being defined, but I have defined it already.

```
def check_entries (): #This function checks whether what the user entered is correct for the entry and store

    global customer_name_error_label
    global receipt_numb_error_label
    global item_hired_name_error_label
    global numb_items_hired_error_label
    global numb_items_hired_numb_rel_error_label

    if  customer_name_entry.get () .isalpha ()  and   receipt_number_entry.get().isdigit() and  item_hired_entry.get () .isalpha ():
        if number_of_items_hired_entry.get () .isdigit () and int (number_of_items_hired_entry.get () ) >0 and int (number_of_items_hired_entry.get () )  <500:

            customer_name_error_label.grid_forget ()
            receipt_numb_error_label.grid_forget ()
            item_hired_name_error_label.grid_forget ()
            numb_items_hired_error_label.grid_forget ()
            numb_items_hired_numb_rel_error_label.grid_forget ()
            append_lists ()

   
    else: 

           if customer_name_entry.get () .isalpha () ==False:
            customer_name_error_label=Label (main_frame,text="Please enter a name that only has letters,no numbers ,and there must be a name entered ",bg='red')
            customer_name_error_label.grid (row=0,column=3)
     
            if receipt_number_entry.get () .isdigit() ==False:
                receipt_numb_error_label=Label (main_frame,text="Please enter a receipt number that is only a number and doesn't have any letters or symbols.",bg='red')
                receipt_numb_error_label.grid(row=1,column=3)

            if item_hired_entry.get () .isalpha ()== False:
                item_hired_name_error_label=Label (main_frame,text="Please enter a item name that only has letters,numbers and symbols aren't accepted.",bg='red')
                item_hired_name_error_label.grid (row=2,column=3)
           
           if number_of_items_hired_entry.get ().isdigit ()== False:
               numb_items_hired_error_label=Label (main_frame,text="The number of items hired can only be a number,symbols,and letters aren't accepted.",bg='red')
               numb_items_hired_error_label.grid (row=4,column=3)

           if int (number_of_items_hired_entry.get () ) <0 and int (number_of_items_hired_entry.get () ) >500:
               numb_items_hired_numb_rel_error_label=Label (main_frame,text="The number of items hired can only be more then 0 and less then 500",bg='red')
               numb_items_hired_numb_rel_error_label.grid (row=5,column=2)
```

[image: Here is the image of what I'm entering]

Here is the error:

```
line 19, in check_entries
    customer_name_error_label.grid_forget ()
NameError: name 'customer_name_error_label' is not defined
```

Comment: Why don't you trust the error message? It says you have never defined `customer_name_error_label`. `global` is not a variable declaration statement.

Comment: Evidently the code trying to access `customer_name_error_label` is being hit before the code that assigns to `customer_name_error_label`.

Comment: Presumably, line 19 is executed _before_ you define it.

Comment: I need it to be used before the declaration, because its the only way I know to get the error labels to delete after the user enters the right names and numbers and the if statements before the else are met and the error warnings disappear.